# How to define tf.layer.dense in a for loop for creating dynamics number of hidden layers and hidden unit?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am looking for a way where we can use tensorflow API to create a neural network with the number of layer and hidden units as user defined.

Lets say I have a neural network like this

```
hidden1 =  tf.layers.dense(inp, units=32, kernel_initializer=tf.initializers.he_uniform(),activation=tf.nn.relu, name="hidden1")

bn1 = tf.layers.batch_normalization(inputs=hidden1, name="bn1")

hidden2 =  tf.layers.dense(bn1, units=16, kernel_initializer=tf.initializers.he_uniform(),activation=tf.nn.relu, name="hidden2")

bn2 = tf.layers.batch_normalization(inputs=hidden2, name="bn2")

hidden3 =  tf.layers.dense(bn2, units=8 , kernel_initializer=tf.initializers.he_uniform(),activation=tf.nn.relu, name="hidden3")

bn3 = tf.layers.batch_normalization(inputs=hidden3, name="bn3")

out = tf.layers.dense(bn3, units=1, kernel_initializer=tf.initializers.he_uniform(), activation=None, name="out")
```

In the above snippet you can notice, if I want 3 layers then I need to repeat the code for 3 times.

I am looking for a way, where we can use `for loop` to define the above code block. For example, if number of layers is defined as 3, then the for loop should iterate and assign units and activation value for each according to user defined.

```
# psuedocode
for i in range(number_of_layer):
        hidden_(i) =  tf.layers.dense(inp, units=32, kernel_initializer=tf.initializers.he_uniform(),activation=tf.nn.relu, name="hidden_(i)")

        bn_(i) = tf.layers.batch_normalization(inputs=hidden_(i), name="bn_(i)")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using tensorflow API

```
inp = tf.placeholder("float", [None,2],name="inp")

units = [32, 16, 8]

for unit in range(len(units)):
     inp =  tf.layers.dense(inp, units=units[unit], kernel_initializer=tf.initializers.he_uniform(),activation=tf.nn.relu,name="hidden" + str(unit + 1))
     inp = tf.layers.batch_normalization(inputs=inp, name="bn"+str(unit + 1))


out = tf.layers.dense(inp, units=1, kernel_initializer=tf.initializers.he_uniform(), activation=None, name="out")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```py
from keras.layers import Dense, BatchNormalization, Dropout
from keras.layers.advanced_activations import ReLU
from keras.models import Model


# Define the number of units per hidden layer
layer_widths = [128, 64, 32]

# Set up input layer
input_layer = Input(...)  # change according to your input
x = input_layer.output

# Iteratively add the hidden layers
for n_neurons in layer_widths:
            x = Dense(n_neurons)(x)
            x = ReLU()(x)
            x = BatchNormalization()(x)
            x = Dropout(0.5)(x)

# Add the output layer
output  = Dense(16, activation='softmax')(x)  # change according to your output

# Stack the model together
model = Model(input, output)
```

Comment: Is it using tf.layer.dense? it would be helpful, if you could add import statements for clarity

Comment: @ITMSEC It is using keras.layers instead of tf.layer. I edited my answer to include the import statements. However, the [functional API](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model) should work with tf.keras in the same way.